# Update Activity From Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have a custom array adapter named **CustomListCartItem**. I want to update my activity whenever a cart item was removed. So far, I can delete an item in my cart list, and also delete the item in **ArrayAdapter**. However, I want to update a TextView named txtSubtotal in my activity.

1. Is the `btnRemove.setOnClickListener` correctly placed?
2. How can I change the value of `txtSubtotal` ?

**My custom array adapter:**

```
public class CustomListCartItem extends ArrayAdapter<ModelCartItem> {
    public CustomListCartItem(Activity context, ArrayList<ModelCartItem> cartItems) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_cart_item, cartItems);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.single_cart_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView txtItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
        ImageView imgItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
        EditText txtQuantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
        Button btnRemove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

        final ModelCartItem cartItem = getItem(position);
        if (cartItem!= null) {
            txtItemName.setText(cartItem.modelItem.itemName);
            Integer imageRes = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cartItem.modelItem.imageName, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
            imgItem.setImageResource(imageRes);
            txtQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(cartItem.quantity));

            btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Controller.removeCartItem(cartItem.modelItem); //remove from cart
                    remove(cartItem); //remove from adapter
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My activity:

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        TextView txtSubtotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSubtotal);
        txtSubtotal.setText(Controller.getCartSubtotal());

        CustomListCartItem adapter = new
                CustomListCartItem(CartActivity.this, Controller.getCartItems());
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to notify your adapter after your data is changed.

Comment: you can create interface and implement it in Activity class.Add listeners in adapter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a listener in my Activity.

**CartActivity:**

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomListCartItem.ItemListener {

@Override
    public void onRemove(ModelCartItem cartItem) {
        Controller.removeCartItem(cartItem.modelItem);
        updateSubtotal();
    }
```

**For CustomListCartItem inside getView:**

```
if (itemListener != null) {
    itemListener.onRemove(cartItem);
}
```

Interface:

```
private ItemListener itemListener;

public void setItemListener(ItemListener listener) {
    this.itemListener = listener;
}

public interface ItemListener {
    void onRemove(ModelCartItem cartItem);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a method to update TextView data in your CartActivity.

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtSubtotal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        txtSubtotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSubtotal);
        txtSubtotal.setText(Controller.getCartSubtotal());

        CustomListCartItem adapter = new
                CustomListCartItem(CartActivity.this, Controller.getCartItems());
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void updateData(String data){
        txtSubtotal.setText(data);
    }
}
```

Access that method in your adapter and change value when you remove.

```
btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Controller.removeCartItem(cartItem.modelItem); //remove from cart
                remove(cartItem); //remove from adapter
               ((CartActivity)context).updateData("Your updated data")
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Add method in activity

```
updateSubTotal(String str) {
    txtSubtotal.setTExt(str); //str OR whatvever you need to set.  
}
```

**2.** Call `updateSubTotal` in onClick method of button click listener (From custom adapter)

```
((CartActivity)context).updateSubTotal("yourvalue");
```